# Creating a loop with data from other sheets

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I'm trying to create a macro for a Personal Budget worksheet, where there is a cell with tedious work.

Using the "Record Macro" button I traced the coding behind the operation I made in the cell, which is the following:

```
Sub calculo_otherex()
' calculo_otherex Macro
' Cálculo de otros gastos con tarjeta.
'
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=Extractos!R[-89]C[-2]-('Home Expenses'!R[-105]C+'Home Expenses'!R[-60]C+'Home Expenses'!R[-16]C+Health!R[-105]C+Health!R[-67]C+Health!R[-29]C+Gifts!R[-99]C+'Daily Living'!R[-87]C+'Daily Living'!R[-29]C+'Daily Living'!R[20]C+'Daily Living'!R[59]C+'Daily Living'!R[102]C+Entertainment!R[-105]C+Entertainment!R[-67]C+Entertainment!R[-29]C+Entertainment!R[9]C+Transportation!R[-105]C)"
    Range("H129").Select

End Sub
```

As you can see, in the formula I refer to other sheets, and to specific cells which reflect a result of a certain month (in this case July) and a specific subset (charges to a credit card).

What I want to do is insert a loop so this procedure repeats for all the months, but the problem is that the data in the sheet "Extractos" appears every 7th cell to the right from "Extractos!R[-89]C[-2]", as the other data in the formula appears in the next column.

How could I solve this??
Thank you very much.

Comment: Try googling `for loop step`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the following a try...  It's hard to read R1C1, so I changed it up a bit and you'll need to replace all my "A1" references to the first month's cell reference.  Also, the `for loop` will only loop 12 times - 12 months in a year.  You can manually change this if you'd like.  Lastly, the formula will be written in the `activecell` then the following formulas will be written in the next cell/column to the right.

```
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'instead of using R1C1, use ranges with offsets - it's much easier to read :) ''
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

'I used "A1" as a placeholder.  Replace this with the actual cell reference for the first month
'The first loop will use the "A1" range.  Then, the 2nd and following loops will move over 1 or 7 columns
'i = move over 1 column
'x = move over 7 columns

For i = 0 To 11 'this will loop through 12 times 0-11
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, i).Formula = _
        "=Extractos!" & Range("A1").Offset(0, x).Address _
        & "-('Home Expenses'!" & Range("A1").Offset(0, i).Address _
        & "+'Home Expenses'!" & Range("A1").Offset(0, i).Address _
        & "+'Home Expenses'!" & Range("A1").Offset(0, i).Address _
        & "+Health!" & Range("A1").Offset(0, i).Address _
        & "+Health!" & Range("A1").Offset(0, i).Address _
        & "+Health!" & Range("A1").Offset(0, i).Address _
        & "+Gifts!" & Range("A1").Offset(0, i).Address _
        & "+'Daily Living'!" & Range("A1").Offset(0, i).Address _
        & "+'Daily Living'!" & Range("A1").Offset(0, i).Address _
        & "+'Daily Living'!" & Range("A1").Offset(0, i).Address _
        & "+'Daily Living'!" & Range("A1").Offset(0, i).Address _
        & "+'Daily Living'!" & Range("A1").Offset(0, i).Address _
        & "+Entertainment!" & Range("A1").Offset(0, i).Address _
        & "+Entertainment!" & Range("A1").Offset(0, i).Address _
        & "+Entertainment!" & Range("A1").Offset(0, i).Address _
        & "+Entertainment!" & Range("A1").Offset(0, i).Address _
        & "+Transportation!" & Range("A1").Offset(0, i).Address & ")"

    'add 7 to x variable
    x = x + 7

'loop and add 1 to i
Next i

'macro done, select H129
Range("H129").Select
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. The way you that structured it is what I was needing to complete this macro. However, when I try to run it the result is 0, and it should deliver a number 0< given the input data.  Do you know why would this be? 
Shoul I use a !Dim as Integer" line?

Comment: For your code to be more complete you could include `Dim x as integer` and do the same for `i`, but it's not necessary - and it's not the issue.  What you need to do is check the formula that gets written in the cell on the actual worksheet.  The Macro is right, you need to fix the formula... and only you can do that :).  good luck!

Comment: Yeah, I found out what the problem was. Somewhere in the running of the macro a "Circular Reference" error occured, where the macro ran not only in the cell selected but in another cell that was included in the formula. Already fixed it. Thank you for the help, was really helpful.